# Creating bitronix transaction manager in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bitronix

I am trying to create the spring-boot transaction manager bean as follows:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
public static TransactionManager bitronixTransactionManager() {
    return TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager();
}
```

However I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot change the configuration while the transaction manager is running
    at bitronix.tm.Configuration.checkNotStarted(Configuration.java:699)
    at bitronix.tm.Configuration.setServerId(Configuration.java:145)
```

I believe this is cause I am calling .getTransactionManager() myself.

However If i do not, how would I create the transaction manager.

The equivalent xml would be:

```
<bean id="bitronixTransactionManager" class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" 
          factory-method="getTransactionManager" destroy-method="shutdown" depends-on="bitronixConfig" />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bitronix support has been added to Spring Boot 1.2. You might want to give the latest snapshots a try. There is a sample application [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jta-bitronix).